# On feature branch git pull --rebase results in remote is diverged

Tags: git

So I have an few weeks old feature branch that I want to rebase to current origin master so it is up to date. First I update local feature branch.
Then I run `git pull -r origin master` and it is all ok. But when I want to push it to remote, it says it is diverged. As I didn't use this often not sure is this normal or a problematic. I can force push it and it will be ok, but need some advice on this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logical: if you rebase your branch on a new version of `master`, then all your commits on your branch have been rewritten. The only way to push these to the remote is to use `git push --force` (or better: `git push --force-with-lease`).

If you want to check what you are going to *overwrite* when using `git push --force-with-lease`, then you can run:

```
git diff @{u} HEAD
```

which means: difference between the upstream (`@{u}`) and your current commit that you are about to push. In your case this should show all new code commited on master.